# На сколько правильно предоставляется ссылка и запрет перехода по ней?

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго вам времени суток Товарищи! Пишу свою CMS систему, и для удобства пользователя и для экономии трафика страницы будет строится методом ajax запроса килент-сервер запрашивая только часть страницы, ссылки модифицированы следующим образом :

```
<a href="?module=show_page" onclick="window.location.hash='asdasdas';return false;">ссылка</a>
```

Что здесь сделано :

1. **href="?module=show_page"** - "нормальная" ссылка, которую можно скопировать, ссылка по которой поисковик сможет перейти.
2. **onclick="window.location.hash='asdasdas';return false;"** - здесь **window.location.hash='asdasdas';** это некая функция, которая будет осуществлять переход(обмен данными с сервер через ajax запрос), а **return false;** как раз запретит браузеру переход по ссылке, и разрешит выполнение **window.location.hash='asdasdas';**

**Вопрос : На сколько этот метод кросбраузерный?**

Проверял в FF 11.0 , Opera 11.60 , Chrome 17.0.963.79 m , IE 8 , результат положительный, всё выполняется как и требовалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот на нативе нацарапал)

```
window.onload = function()
{
var url = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0, l = url.length; i < l; ++i)
{    
    url[i].onclick = function()
    {
        alert(this.href);
        // Ajax
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Только вот в цикле не надо каждый раз считать length. Т.е. вместо 

     for( var i=0; i<url.length; ++i ){}

Намного лучше, особенно в данной ситуации

     for( var i=0, l=url.length; i<l; ++i ) {} 

PS: вместо `this.getAttribute("href")` достаточно просто `this.href`

Comment: Очередной раз учел!) И исправил целиком код.

Comment: Ага, осталась самая малость: саму подгрузку на нативе нацарапать ;)

Comment: @Syabrowka сложностей не возникало, но это тут лишнее!

Comment: IE 6 супортят только мазохисты, для остальных это `new XMLHttpRequest`, в остальном все просто. Если вам интересно задайте вопрос и я приведу вам пример элементарно простого врапера для ajax'a, jquery и ему подобные не магия, всего-лишь код, написанный на все том-же javascript'e

Comment: У меня всё реализовано, без jquery, не люблю я библиотеки=)

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Не совсем, дак будет ли работать мой код даже в самых древних браузерах?)

Comment: Этот пример - да, вообще непонятно зачем вы хотите поддержку ископаемых? Вы же типа современную CMS пишите, только геммора и тормозов себе добавите. Если же, все-так, вы хотите поддерживать ископаемые - писать весь код руками мазахизм, юзайте jquery или, любителям native js он нравиться больше - prototype.

Вообще ИМХО  ie7+ было бы достаточно, даже ie8+ было бы достаточно т.к. напишите вы ее не за один день.

Comment: Благодарю.

Comment: getElementsByTagName в IE6 не работает по-моему....

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай протестил этот скрипт в IE6 все чудно!

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно неправильно.
Ссылка должна иметь стандартный вид: `<a href="/link/to/page/>`
А если надо аякс, то в спиециательном файлике пишется:

`$(function(){$("a").click(function(){
    $("#content").load($(this).attr("href")+"?ajax=Y",function(){
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href"); });
        return false;
    })
})`

Это в общих чертах главная суть.

По ссылке должна быть доступна страница целиком, как она должна быть без аякса.
параметр ?ajax=Y следует передавать на сервер для того, чтобы сервер сообразил, надо ли контент оборачивать шаблоном или отдать в чистом виде.
Адрес в хэш пишется чтобы иметь возможность дать прямую ссылку на эту страницу. Соответственно, должен быть ещё обработчик этого хэша, подгружающий нужный контент.

Comment: Всё, что вы говорите - реализовано, суть вопроса : в каких браузерах мой код будет работать правильно.

Comment: А что он должен делать? Записывать в хэш некую функцию? зачем?

Comment: Нет, window.location.hash='asdasdas'; это демонстрация того, что функция сможет выполнится и браузер не перейдёт по ссылке. Заместо window.location.hash='asdasdas'; будет стоять функция, которая осуществляется ajax запрос, а точнее её вызов.

Comment: > Всё, что вы говорите - реализовано

@Андрей Аршинов если присваивать каждой ссылке вашу реализацию, это плохая реализация!

Comment: > Заместо window.location.hash='asdasdas'; будет стоять функция

Тюхать в каждую ссылку onclick тоже не айс!

Comment: Почему же?

Comment: Потому что делая хороший подход к построению CMS, функция Ajax подгрузки данных должна иметь возможность включаться и отключаться. Если у Вас в каждой ссылке будет наглухо забит onclick, это уже избавляет систему от такой возможности! Один из вариантов!

Comment: более того, обработчик перехода по ссылке может содержать в себе кода более чем на одну строку, зависеть от ряда условий, применяться(или не применяться) к определённой области на сайте.

В общем, не надо onclick. По первости работать будет, а потом сами под этим закопаетесь.